# Help identifying what font is this:

Tags: font-identification

I can't find out what font is this:

[image]

I have used this awesome service where you upload a picture and it tells you what's the font is, but I don't agree. The 'a' is different. [Here is the result.](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=M&ch%5B1%5D=a&ch%5B2%5D=k&ch%5B3%5D=e&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=00397aaf535186d5000a40200000712c&glyphcount=4&imageid=0&x=60&y=30)

And here is an screenshot of the font's this service proposed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminds me of DIN, DIN Next comes pretty close:

http://www.linotype.com/517415/dinnext-family.html

Comment: Please can you add a screenshot of the font you found on this page?  Suppose the link is down then your answer seems to be useless. With picture not.

Answer (score 1):

granby EF bold is probably your best bet.

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef/granby/ef-bold/

I believe it was also narrowed horizontally in photoshop to about 75-85%.